# Jquery UI: Dialog launched from button on a tab briefly shows the dialog, then closes it and opens the 1st tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm pretty new to jquery, and I'm having a problem I can't seem to fix.

So, I have some [Jquery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default). On the second tab I have a button that when clicked is supposed to launch a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).
I previously had some accordions with this same code and it worked fine.

The behavior goes as follows, on IE, Chrome, and FF: The dialog briefly appears when the button on the second tab (#create-file) is clicked, then closes immediately. The first tab, instead of the second tab, then becomes active.
When trying to find a solution, I turned autoOpen from false to true - then the dialog showed when I clicked the button, but of course, it showed when the page was first loaded - not a solution. Here is my code.

JS:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#fileform").dialog(
{
      show: 'fade',
      hide: 'fade',
      autoOpen : false,
  height : 300,
  width : 350,
  modal : true,
  buttons : {
    "Save" : function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
         }
    },
Cancel : function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
close : function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
$("#create-file").button().click(function() {
    $("#fileform").dialog("open");
});
```

HTML:
(Actual display)

```
<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#TAB1">TAB 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#TAB2">TAB 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="TAB1">
        <p>LOREM IPSUM KLJLKJLKJKLJKLJHGHGFHGJHLKJH</p>
        </div>
        <div id="TAB2">
                    <div class="scrollable">
                                <ol class="selectable" id="supportfiles">
                                        </ol>
                                    </div>
                <button id="create-file">Save File</button>
        </div>
```

Dialog code:

```
            <div id="fileform" title="New File">
        <p class="validateTips">Please enter data.</p>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="filepath">File</label> <input type="file"
                    name="filepath" id="filepath"
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> <label
                    for="description">Description</label> <input type="text"
                    name="description" id="description" value=""
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is everything](http://jsbin.com/eyeveb/1/edit) working. You've closed too many braces before defining your cancel button. Cancel isn't an event like `open` and `close`.

```
buttons: {
    "Save": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
}
```